# QT QTcpSocket miss some data after start write data to server

Tags: qt, sockets, tcp, qtcpsocket

I get sine wave from server though TCP and plot it. Everything seems to be fine until I start sending something back at c>1000. After one byte sent, I still get data but the waveform of sine wave is changed. I'm sure that there are some missed data but I can't find bugs in my code. The transmission rate is about 1M bps.

The question is

1. When I write something to server, how it effects to socket?
2. Why the socket miss some data?
3. How can I fix it?

   ```
   ssTcpClient::ssTcpClient(QObject *parent) :
   QObject(parent)
   {
       socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
       connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()),
               this, SLOT(on_connected()));
       connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()),
               this, SLOT(on_disconnected()));
   }

   void ssTcpClient::on_connected()
   {
       qDebug() << "Client: Connection established.";
       connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
               this, SLOT(on_readyRead()));
       in = new QDataStream(socket);
   }

   void ssTcpClient::on_readyRead(){
       static quint32 c = 0;
       qDebug() << "c" << c++;

       QVector<quint8> data;
       quint8 buf;
       while(socket->bytesAvailable()>0){
           //read data to buffer
           *in >> buf;
           data.append(buf);
       }
       //process data
       emit data_read(data);

       //if there are over 1000 data then send something back
       if(c>1000){
           char msg[10];
           msg[0] = 'c';
           socket->write(msg,1);
           socket->flush();
       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot rely on TCP traffic to be complete, data arrives in indeterminable chunks.

You are using `QDataStream` to read data from the socket. This is a really bad idea because `QDataStream` assumes that you have complete set of data. If there isn't enough data, it will silently fail.

I suggest you modify your data source so it either sends a byte count as the first thing, or it sends some kind of termination sequence that you can look out for to tell you that you have received enough to process.